# Can I ask a retail store for video & audio they may have of me?

Tags: discovery, slander

https://g.co/kgs/Mprheh

Please read the link I provided. It will take you to a Google review I have left for a retail store in my area. It'll explain it all!
Thank you for all and everyone's help.
Also, I spoke with the store manager this afternoon and he said that I was accused of verbally attacking an associate (which I didn't do) and pointing my finger at her (they won't tolerate that!) LOL
I may have pointed my finger at her but that was it....oh, I did tell one of them to get off her "high horse" and she told me to quit calling her names lololol!!!!
I've got a call into the corporate customer service.  Is there anything else I can or should do?
I don't care if I shop there again but they have my name on a piece of paper by the registers that says "rude " " banned"

Comment: Where is this ?

Comment: You seem to have left an “n” off the end of your name in your profile.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I ask a retail store for video & audio they may have of me?

According to your Google review, you were "*informed that [the] store doesn't have video surveillance*". This suggests that asking the retail store for video & audio would be unavailing: The store cannot give you something that does not exist.

> Is there anything else I can or should do?

Apparently not. It is within the store's *freedom of contract* you refuse to do business with someone, provided that the reason for refusal does not constitute unlawful discrimination, deceitful practice, or maybe few other motives. Your description does not seem to fit any of those categories.

> they have my name on a piece of paper by the registers that says "rude " " banned"

Placing on the cashier a piece of paper with your name and the words "rude" and/or "banned" is not defamatory. The word "rude" would qualify as *statement of opinion*, and claims of defamation are only about *statements of fact*. The word "banned" is a *statement of fact*, but it seemingly is a true one since the manager notified you that you are no longer allowed to shop there. Claims of defamation are about *false* statements of fact.

Lastly, it is unclear from your description and Google review whether or how the store got your name. Unless you paid with cash or gift card, the matter of the receipt would be clarified by looking/showing the bank account record of the purchase.